# IntelliJ Idea lost AppEngine integration over git

Tags: git, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I got a repository for an AppEngine application made in IntelliJ.
When my colleague clone the repo to work on it, the project lost every reference to AppEngine (although he has it on his computer) and he must add each library manually.

Is there a way to avoid that?

This is my .gitignore, generated witgh gitignore.io

```
### AppEngine ###
# Google App Engine generated folder
appengine-generated/


### Intellij ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm

*.iml

## Directory-based project format:
.idea/
# if you remove the above rule, at least ignore the following:

# User-specific stuff:
# .idea/workspace.xml
# .idea/tasks.xml
# .idea/dictionaries

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
# .idea/dataSources.ids
# .idea/dataSources.xml
# .idea/sqlDataSources.xml
# .idea/dynamic.xml
# .idea/uiDesigner.xml

# Gradle:
# .idea/gradle.xml
# .idea/libraries

# Mongo Explorer plugin:
# .idea/mongoSettings.xml

## File-based project format:
*.ipr
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
/out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml
```

Comment: I think you should contact intellij support

Answer (score 1):

this may not be the answer you are looking for but i have had the best results accross multiple IDEs by using maven for all app engine projects. IntelliJ has excellent support for maven (even the community edition) so i really recommend using maven. By using maven you also eliminate the requirement for any app engine plugins, etc. It just works.

Upon request, this is a maven pom.xml i use in one of my projects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.konqi.konqiapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <appengine.target.version>1.9.12</appengine.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints</directory>
                            <!-- the list has a default value of ** -->
                            <includes>
                                <include>WEB-INF/*.discovery</include>
                                <include>WEB-INF/*.api</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <jvmFlags>
                        <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
                        <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>endpoints_get_discovery_doc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</project>
```

Comment: can you share how you enable app engine with maven?

Comment: sure - added the pom.xml. Make sure to also check out https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven . Once you place the pom.xml in your project root you can open the project as maven project in IntelliJ. I have all IntelliJ-related stuff in .gitignore so the project will be imported by the pom and not some (often bogus) settings in you project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I work with Intelij Idea & App Engine, I include the `.idea` directory in the repository, but exclude workspace.xml. It works best for me